# Asp.net pie chart how to display different values in legends and yvaluemember

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, pie-chart

The following is the code:
**ASPX** code

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="414px" Height="396px" BackColor="Transparent"
            Palette="SeaGreen">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Education" XValueMember="State" YValueMembers="Education" IsVisibleInLegend="true"
                    ChartType="Pie" Color="255, 255, 128">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true">
                    <AxisX LineColor="DarkGray">
                        <MajorGrid LineColor="LightGray" />
                    </AxisX>
                    <AxisY LineColor="DarkGray">
                        <MajorGrid LineColor="LightGray" />
                    </AxisY>
                    <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" WallWidth="5" LightStyle="Realistic"></Area3DStyle>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend>
                </asp:Legend>
            </Legends>
        </asp:Chart>
```

**CS** code

```
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Education", typeof(long));

table.Columns.Add("Lbl");
var row = table.NewRow();
row["State"] = "Gujarat";
row["Education"] = 791;

table.Rows.Add(row);
row = table.NewRow();
row["State"] = "Delhi";
row["Education"] = 978;
table.Rows.Add(row);

row = table.NewRow();
row["State"] = "Panjab";
row["Education"] = 1650;
table.Rows.Add(row);

Chart1.DataSource = table;
Chart1.DataBind();
```

My issue is i want to display different values in legends and different in the actual piechart area labels. How can i do it?

I tried various combinations, but did not get through al i want is the legends should contain values from one column and pie chart values from another column. Here is a picture of what exactly i want
[image]

Column `Education` contains integer values which i want to display in the chart area.

kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Series` property to `IsValueShownAsLabel="true"`